# Forcing an ayncio coroutine to start

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'm currently writing some unit tests for a system that uses asyncio so I'd like to be able to force an asyncio coroutine to run to an `await` point. As an example, consider the following:

```py
import asyncio

event = asyncio.Event()

async def test_func():
    print('Test func')
    await event.wait()

async def main():
    w = test_func()
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    print('Post func')
    event.set()
    print('Post set')
    await w
    print('Post wait')

asyncio.run(main())
```

If I run this program with Python 3.7 I see the following output

```
Post func
Post set
Test func
Post wait
```

I'd like to be able to test the case where the event isn't set before the coroutine starts running - i.e. have the output

```
Test func
Post func
Post set
Post wait
```

Is there a way to force the coroutine to start running until it reaches the `await` point. I've tried using an `asyncio.sleep(0)` statement but even if I sleep for a number of seconds the `test_func` coroutine doesn't start until `await` is hit in `main`.

If this isn't possible is there another option for creating this test case?

Answer (score 0):

I need to create a task to execute the coroutine so there is another task for asyncio to schedule. If instead of calling `w = test_func()` I use `w = asyncio.create_task(test_func())` and follow that with `asyncio.sleep(0)`. I get the behaviour I desire. I'm not sure how deterministic the asyncio event loop at scheduling tasks but it seems to be working reliably for this example.